# JavaScript: Call init function vs. returning that function call

Tags: javascript, function, return, init

Under what circumstances would I choose to do this:

```
function foo(){
    
    function setup(){
        // do some stuff   
    }
    
    function moreSetup(){
        // and more and more
    }
    
    function init(){
        // init stuff
    }
    
    init();
}
```

And under what circumstances would I prefer this?

```
function foo(){
    
    function setup(){
        // do some stuff   
    }
    
    function moreSetup(){
        // and more and more
    }
    
    function init(){
        // init stuff
    }
    
    return{       
        init();
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries. :) If you didn't ask, you'd still be confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is invalid:

```
return{       
        init();
    }
```

The `{ ... }` defines an object literal which must contain key-value pairs, like `{ foo: 'bar' }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will do the stuff within `init` and return `undefined`.

Your second example is invalid.  I think you wanted:

```
return init()
```

without curly braces.  This will return the result of `init` (which you haven't specified).  In both cases, `setup` and `moreSetup` never get called, so I'm not sure why they're there.

You've left out a lot of details, but my answer right now is: if the caller needs to do something with the result of `init` you'll need to go with option #2.

Answer (score 0):

No offense meant, but this seems like a somewhat confused question.  As others have noted, you shouldn't have the brackets around `init()` in the second example.  And when you say `function setup() { ... }` you're just defining the function, not calling it -- meaning in this example the function never gets called.

But the main thing I'm posting this answer to try to address is this: "Call init function vs. returning that function call".  It is incorrect to think that you are "returning the function call" in the second example.  When you say `return init()`, first `init()` is called and returns some value, and then your `foo` function returns the value returned by `init()`.

So that's the question you should be asking.  Do I just want `foo` to call `init`, or do I want `foo` to call `init` and return the value that `init` returns?  That's the difference between the two (once the other errors are removed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still thrilled by the idea of calling your function with init, like I do :), then you could design your function as follows:

```
var mainFunction = function() {
  var init = () => {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
  }

  function functionOne(){
    console.log('I am the first one');
  }

  function functionTwo(){
    console.log('I came second?');
  }

  return {
   init: init
  };
}(); // please note the () - call the function here or use
// mainFunction().init()

mainFunction.init();
```